# How can I use fixed-sized integers in C?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, types, fixed-width

I'm trying to compile some code which contains the following declaration, because I would like `count` to be a guaranteed 32-bit integer:

```
int32 count;
```

However, this results in an error at compile time:

```
test.c:21: error: ‘int32’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Is there a particular compile-time option that I need to set for GCC, or an `#include` directive that will solve this? How can declare an integer of a fixed bit width on Ubuntu with GCC?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `int32` type isn't standard C - the standard equivalent is to `#include <stdint.h>` and use `int32_t`.

However, as a POSIX system, on Ubuntu plain `int` is (at least) 32 bit so you could just use that.

Comment: Two things of note: 1) `<stdint.h>` is standard, but it's C99 - not a problem for gcc, but can be elsewhere (e.g. MSVC); and 2) POSIX doesn't require `int` to be 32-bit, and there are Unixes out there for which it's not true.

Comment: There are four programming environments allowed by POSIX to be the default (listed here: http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/c99.html#tagtcjh_11 ), all of which require `int` to be at least 32 bits.

Comment: To include the C header `stdint.h` in C++ you `#include <cstdint>`

Answer (score -1):

Size of 'int' depends on the compiler you use. For same target architecture different compilers can have different sizes for 'int'. It depends on how they are utilizing the target features. For example, Turbo C running on windows has 'int' size as 2 bytes (its a DOS executable). While Visual C gives the size of 'int' as 32 (win32 executable).

In general, size of 'int' is determined by the size of word as per the target architecture. Size of word is reflected by
1. Processing size of arithmetic operations.
2. Size of general purpose registers.
3. Size of the address used to designate a location.

However in your case you are wrongly using a keyword 'int32' for a data type. Check the target machine and fix up the keyword used accordingly.

Comment: It's one of the newer `typedef`'s specified in C99, and is available in the header `stdint.h`.

Comment: `int32` is not a keyword in standard C.